# Multi line output in TextArea with JSP

Tags: html, jsp

How can I display my list in a TestArea line after line with no additional spaces. i.e:

```
this
that
the
other
```

Here is my attempt:

```
<div class="text">
    <label for="output_string">Output:</label> `
    <textarea rows="10" cols="20">
        <c:forEach var="x" items="${messagelist}">${x}</c:forEach>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a guess (which I'll try out in just a sec in one of my own pages):

```
<c:forEach var='x' items='${messagelist}'><c:out value='${x}\r\n'/></c:forEach>
```

*edit* — no that doesn't seem to work at all.  However, what did work was for me to add a message catalog entry like this:

```
linebreak={0}\r\n
```

Then you can use `<fmt:message key="linebreak"><fmt:param value="${x}"/></fmt:message>` to produce the string terminated by line breaks.

Note that JSP will put spaces before the first entry according to the indentation in your .jsp source file before the `<c:forEach>`, so you'll have to line everything up at the left edge if you don't want that.

If I had to do this a lot, I'd write an EL add-on function of my own to echo back a string followed by CRLF.

*edit* — If you want to write an EL add-on, you need two things:

- The function itself, which should be a `public static` method of some class. I keep a class around called "ELFunctions" for most of mine.  You can arrange them any way you want.
- A ".tld" file, if you don't already have one. It should end up in your webapp somewhere under "WEB-INF".  Mine goes in a subdirectory called "tld", but you can put it anywhere.

So you would write a little function like this, in some class:

```
public static String linebreak(final String msg) {
    return msg + "\r\n";
}
```

Then your ".tld" file would look like this (assuming it's the only thing you've got; if you have an existing ".tld" file just add the clause):

```
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
  <description>Your Favorite Description</description>
  <display-name>Make Something Up</display-name>
  <tlib-version>4.0</tlib-version>
  <short-name>whatever</short-name>
  <uri>http://yourdomain.com/tld/whatever</uri>

  <function>
    <description>
        Return a string augmented with trailing line break (CR - LF pair)
    </description>
    <name>linebreak</name>
    <function-class>your.package.name.YourClass</function-class>
    <function-signature>
        java.lang.String linebreak(java.lang.String)
    </function-signature>
  </function>
```

(Boy, XML is so annoying.)  Now somewhere you probably already have a little file that pulls in taglibs for your pages (for `<c:...>` tags at least).  In there, or at the top of any page, add a line like this:

```
  <%@ taglib prefix="whatever" uri='http://yourdomain.com/tld/tango' %>
```

I *think* that the JSP runtime searches for ".tld" files by looking through the WEB-INF subtree, and in .jar files in WEB-INF/lib, matching by that "uri" string.  Anyway, once you've done that, in your JSP file you can say:

```
  <c:forEach var='x' items='${messagelist}'>${whatever:linebreak(x)}</c:forEach>
```

and it'll invoke your function.

Comment: Message Catolog Entry?  Is that added to Web.xml?

Comment: No, it's a .properties file that's accessed as a ResourceBundle. I have the "luxury" of having that around due to the framework I'm using, but I'm not exactly sure what you have to do to make it work. I know that the file has to end up in the CLASSPATH via your build; in my tree, they go into the root of the "classes" directory.

Comment: If you're not working with message catalogs now, adding an EL function might be a lot easier.  In fact you could write an EL function that'd spit out the whole list, if you wanted to.  I'll add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:set var="xv"></c:set>
<c:forEach items="${messagelist}" var="x">
    <c:if test="${not empty x}">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${idx.first}"><c:set var="xv" value="${x}"></c:set></c:when>
        <c:otherwise><c:set var="xv" value="${xv},${x}"></c:set></c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
<textarea cols="45" rows="5">${xv}</textarea>
```